# How to do a moving average on a range of dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's just say I have two columns, DATE and VALUE. The dates are not necessarily regularly spaced intervals. How can I create a moving average on VALUE over the past N days? I'm using postgres but mysql solutions would also be helpful.

Data:

```
DATE    VALUE
2012-11-05 10
2012-10-29 31
2012-10-22 108
2012-10-17 3654
2012-10-16 1187
2012-10-15 12033
2012-10-09 41
2012-10-01 85
2012-09-25 20
2012-09-24 285
2012-09-17 20
2012-09-10 20
2012-09-04 41
2012-08-27 63
2012-08-20 52
2012-08-13 160
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: John, I mean running averages. So each row should contain the average of the value for the past N days (where N is arbitrary) including the current day.

Comment: how do your desired result looked like?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain any better. Each row should contain the average for the past N days in a column called "MV_AVG" or something to that effect.

Comment: @Glenn, why did you delete your answer? It's the right solution, and it's what was writing when I saw yours. I've posted anyway; ping me if you want me to delete it if you re-create yours.

Comment: @Glenn Aah, you deleted it because the question wants an average over the last `n` *days*, not the last `n` records, and there's no guarantee that there's one record per day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MySQL example below covers a sliding 7-day window:

```
select t1.`DATE`, AVG(t2.`VALUE`) as MV_AVG
from MyTable t1
left outer join MyTable t2 
    on t2.`DATE` between DATE_ADD(t1.`DATE`, INTERVAL -6 DAY) 
        and t1.`DATE`
group by t1.`DATE`
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d659/4)

**Output:**

```
|                             DATE |    MV_AVG |
------------------------------------------------
|    August, 12 2012 20:00:00+0000 |       160 |
|    August, 19 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        52 |
|    August, 26 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        63 |
| September, 03 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        41 |
| September, 09 2012 20:00:00+0000 |      30.5 |
| September, 16 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        20 |
| September, 23 2012 20:00:00+0000 |       285 |
| September, 24 2012 20:00:00+0000 |     152.5 |
| September, 30 2012 20:00:00+0000 |      52.5 |
|   October, 08 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        41 |
|   October, 14 2012 20:00:00+0000 |      6037 |
|   October, 15 2012 20:00:00+0000 |      6610 |
|   October, 16 2012 20:00:00+0000 | 5624.6667 |
|   October, 21 2012 20:00:00+0000 | 1649.6667 |
|   October, 28 2012 20:00:00+0000 |        31 |
|  November, 04 2012 19:00:00+0000 |        10 |
```

Comment: After quoting the '-6' in the `INTERVAL` term, changing the MySQL ```` quotes to ANSI `""` quotes or removing them, changing `DATE_ADD` to use of the `+` operator and adding an `ORDER BY`, this query also works on PostgreSQL (See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/275eb/8)... but I'd use a window function solution there instead.

Comment: I'd actually like to see a solution with a window function.

Comment: @EvanZamir I don't have time to look it up, not a Postgres user. Should be easy to find examples, though. One advantage of the above solution is that it is quite portable across platforms (as Craig has shown), just the date function differs.

Answer (score 5):

RedFilter's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280831/1432614) uses non-evenly spaced buckets. If you want evenly spaced buckets do something like this:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL ((i.id - 0) * 7) - 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS start,
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL ((i.id - 1) * 7) DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS end,
AVG(d.value) average
FROM
ids i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dates d ON
d.date BETWEEN 
  (CURDATE() - INTERVAL ((i.id - 0) * 7) - 1 DAY) AND
  (CURDATE() - INTERVAL ((i.id - 1) * 7) DAY)
WHERE
i.id BETWEEN 0 AND 20
GROUP BY
1
ORDER BY
1 DESC;
```

which provides this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| start      | end        | average   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2012-11-01 | 2012-11-07 |   10.0000 |
| 2012-10-25 | 2012-10-31 |   31.0000 |
| 2012-10-18 | 2012-10-24 |  108.0000 |
| 2012-10-11 | 2012-10-17 | 5624.6667 |
| 2012-10-04 | 2012-10-10 |   41.0000 |
| 2012-09-27 | 2012-10-03 |   85.0000 |
| 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-26 |  152.5000 |
| 2012-09-13 | 2012-09-19 |   20.0000 |
| 2012-09-06 | 2012-09-12 |   20.0000 |
| 2012-08-30 | 2012-09-05 |   41.0000 |
| 2012-08-23 | 2012-08-29 |   63.0000 |
| 2012-08-16 | 2012-08-22 |   52.0000 |
| 2012-08-09 | 2012-08-15 |  160.0000 |
| 2012-08-02 | 2012-08-08 |      NULL |
| 2012-07-26 | 2012-08-01 |      NULL |
| 2012-07-19 | 2012-07-25 |      NULL |
| 2012-07-12 | 2012-07-18 |      NULL |
| 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-11 |      NULL |
| 2012-06-28 | 2012-07-04 |      NULL |
| 2012-06-21 | 2012-06-27 |      NULL |
+------------+------------+-----------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78c52/39 for a working example without CURDATE().

Comment: Because it took me a bit to figure it out:  the ids table is used to both to assist the math for the defining the ranges and to provide "limit" functionality. Testing in SQL Fiddle showed that this method had a better query plan than using "limit 20"

Comment: Minor critique: "BETWEEN 1 AND 20" would represent the values used better and "GROUP BY 1,2" would not depend on MySQL's ability to omit grouping column.